# Fetching location updates using Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, location, kotlin-flow, android-gps

I am new to Kotlin Flow. Currently I am using LocationManager to get user Location updates like below:

```
private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null
locationManager = mContext?.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

if (locationManager != null) {
                        mLocation = locationManager!!
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
                        locationManager!!.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES.toFloat(), locationProviderListener
                        )
                        return mLocation
                    }

private var locationProviderListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            try {
                val latitude = location.latitude
                val longitude = location.longitude
                updateLatitudeLongitude(latitude, longitude)
                updateLocation(location)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(s: String, i: Int, bundle: Bundle) {}
        override fun onProviderEnabled(s: String) {}
        override fun onProviderDisabled(s: String) {}
    }
```

And this works fine. But now I want to get location updates using Kotlin Flow. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe this post could give you some indications using Flow with LocationManager: https://conorsmith.dev/post/kotlin_flow_location_updates/